# Elasticsearch RangeFacet errors for response object in Java API

Tags: elasticsearch

I have crated a range facet for a fields(`CREDITS`) and trying to search it with Match all query and get response as below-

```
facetCreditRange =rangeFacet("Credit").field("CREDITS").addUnboundedFrom(5).addRange(5,10).addUnboundedTo(10);
SearchResponse response1 = client.prepareSearch(index).setTypes(type).addFacet(facetCreditRange).setQuery(matchAllQuery()).execute().actionGet();
```

when I run this code it gives me error -

> <[Arsenal] Message
>   not fully read (response) for [194] handler
>   org.elasticsearch.action.TransportActionNodeProxy$1@fc63c33, error
>   [true], resetting>   
>     
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportSerializationException: Failed to
>   deserialize exception response from stream    at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:169)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:123)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.j

and so on
Please let me know how can I create a range facet for '`Credits`' field with different ranges like '0-5',5-10,10-15.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you swap the values of your addUnboundedFrom and your addUnboundedTo ?

What I read, here, is that you want 3 ranges ..

- bigger than 5
- between 5 and 10
- lower than 10

those ranges are overlapping .. maybe that's the cause of your problem?